# system.profile collection empty even though mongod started with profile level 2

Tags: mongodb, profiling

**Specs**: Win10 64bit, MongoDB v3.6.3

I'm having trouble profiling MongoDB. I have some slow queries for which I wanted to see more details, so I started `mongod` with `--profile 2`. I checked with MongoDB console if the profiler was enabled with `db.getProfilingLevel()` which reports `2` correctly.

However, after running some queries from my application (.Net, official driver) which I'm sure are working as I get correct results, the `system.profile` collection is still empty (`db.system.profile.findOne()` returns `null`).

I'm currently out of ideas what could be the problem and google searches didn't lead to any interesting results. Sometimes after a while the `mongod` contains this output, but it's not generated in response to any query:

`.sessions: CannotImplicitlyCreateCollection: request doesn't allow collection to be created implicitly
2018-04-18T20:10:47.249+0200 I -        [thread53] Creating profile collection: config.system.profile
2018-04-18T20:10:47.250+0200 W -        [thread53] Caught Assertion while trying to profile update against config.system.sessions: CannotImplicitlyCreateCollection: request doesn't allow collection to be created implicitly`

Comment: Having basically the same issue. Any luck finding what was the problem?

Comment: @Justin Sorry, it has been a while. As far as I can remember I didn't resolve the issue but found why the queries were running slow other way and deduced from there.. Basically I had lot of disk reads that were happening rarely with too general queries.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Good to know you were able to still solve your issue. For me it ended up being a naming/usage issue. Went back to the docs to make sure i was typing it properly or need to use another command and ended up getting it working. When I get some time i'll grab that command and post it here for help for others.